# resharper 5.1 test runner using nunit. Cannot see section in config file

Tags: resharper-5.1

Using resharper testrunner and running into a problem that cannot find config sections in my config file.
I have checked the config file and it has all the sections required.

Could it be that for some reason I am missing some settings in resharper  so that it can see these settings in the config files.

any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just a section, my issue was it was totally ignoring the config file.
Turned out the "Copy to Output Directory" setting was "never" instead of "always"

I also have the config named TestAssembly.dll.config - where TestAssembly.dll is the name of the assembly with the fixtures/tests contained. I was told that by a colleague a while back but while googling for my issue couldn't find anything to back this up - it is my ritual anyway now.